# ExtJS RowExpander plugin strange colspan

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Trying to make a grid with a row expander and came across a strange behaviour.

The first row's expanded view get's a colspan of 3 (number of columns in table),
second one gets a colspan of 2 and any following rows get a colspan of 1.

Could someone explain why this is happening and also a way to specify that the contents of the expanded row should fill all of it (colspan set to number of columns in table).

JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6xCPb/1/)

Code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    fields: ['id','name','ship'],
    data: [{
        id: 1, 
        name: 'Kirk',
        ship: 'Enterprise'           
    },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Picard',
        ship: 'Enterprise'
    },{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Janeway',
        ship: 'Voyager'
    },{
        id: 4,
        name: 'Khan',
        ship: 'Reliant'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    title: 'Test',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id'
    },{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    },{
        text: 'Ship',
        dataIndex: 'ship'
    }],
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        rowBodyTpl: [
            '<div class="row-details-panel" id="row-details-panel-{id}">{id} = {name}</div>'
        ]
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (grid) {
            // hide the first row generated by rowExander plugin
            grid.getView().getHeaderAtIndex(0).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a bug of Ext 4.2.0 version. I have run your code at https://fiddle.sencha.com against Ext 4.2.1 and it behaves as expected - the colspan is always 3.

Upgrade to 4.2.1, it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: I tried running the code above (the onReady() was removed) on fiddle.sencha.com (4.2.1 classic). here ALL the rows consistently have colspan 2, not colspan 3 (which would be the full table). Unless I remove the line in the listeners afterrender method, then all the rows get colspan 3 (but then the extra row show up at the front of the table).  Did you change anything to get it to work?

Comment: Post please the link to that fiddle, I'll take a look.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6g1 It's working fine in 5, but 4.2.0 and 4.2.1 both work differently.

Comment: The first problem is that the column does not hide. The reason for that is that afterrender is probably too early. I would probably only set hidden:true on the column config if I would want it to be initially hidden. The second problem is that expander plugin thinks the column is hidden, therefore colspan=2 - `hidden:true` in column config and removing the listener should solve it.

Comment: How do I set hidden:true for the column when it is not in the column config of the grid? (it's added automatically by the rowExpander plugin)

Comment: Ah, now I see the point, you're hiding the expander icon, not ID. You can use this trick then: add `addExpander:Ext.emptyFn` to the plugin config and the expander icon column does not show.

Comment: Thanks that works better than hiding the column afterwards. Still getting only 2 (instead of 3) colspan in 4.2.1, but fixed it by overriding getRowBodyFeatureData() and setting it there